# Posting URL parameter to middleware in Laravel 6

Tags: php, laravel

I need to pass a value from a url to my middleware class to use for further logic. I've seen a lot resources where this is possible for `get` requests, but I haven't seen any for `post` requests. I've tried adding the variable in my route, for example:

```
Route::post('orders/created/{$name}', 'myController@orderCreated');
```

But when making this HTTP request via postman, I receive a 404 request. I can see the route is getting listed correctly, even after clearing cache. As seen below:

```
+--------+----------+------------------------------------+--------+---------------------------------------------------------------+------------------------------+
| Domain | Method   | URI                                | Name   | Action                                                        | Middleware                   |
+--------+----------+------------------------------------+--------+---------------------------------------------------------------+------------------------------+
|        | POST     | webhooks/orders/cancelled/{$name}  |        | App\Http\Controllers\myController@orderCancelled              | web,auth.webhook             |
|        | POST     | webhooks/orders/created/{$name}    |        | App\Http\Controllers\myController@orderCreated                | web,auth.webhook             |
+--------+----------+------------------------------------+--------+---------------------------------------------------------------+------------------------------+
```

I've tried adding the `Request $request, $name` parameters in my middleware function, but I am unsure of what I am doing wrong. Is this even possible to do so with Laravel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the url, you should omit the $, like this

```
Route::post('orders/created/{name}', 'myController@orderCreated');
```

Then you can access it in your middleware from the `$request`object, like this

```
$request->route('name');
```

Comment: This was the fix, I was going crazy trying to figure out why it didn't work. Thank you!